# Program exit state

Tags: c, linux, exit, exit-code

I have a question about program exit state in Linux. In my program, I fork a child process and invoke `waitpid` to reap it. When `waitpid` returns, I wanna check exit state of my child process. I turn to manual for help and find that the second argument of `waitpid` will hold exit state and I can use macro `WEXITSTATE` to read it. However, this macro just extract least significant 8 bits of the real exit state, while in manual of function `exit(int ret_val)`, it will exit with `ret_val & 0x377`, instead of least significant 8 bits.

My question is, where is the other more bits? Do we simply drop them? Why Linux employ this strategy? Doesn't this implementation introduce trouble to our program?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will find that `0x377` is really, or should have been, `0377`.

It's octal, so   **377**<sub>8</sub>   is 8 bits.

Comment: I mistake 0377 as hex. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Exit return values are only suppose to be between 0 and 255 per the POSIX spec.  You shouldn't be returning values higher than that (in other words a POSIX-compliant OS will only be concerned with the lower eight-bits of your exit return value, and that's all that will be passed to the parent process).

Comment: And of course, the other bits of the status hold things like whether the process dumped core and what signal brought it down (if it did not exit normally).

Answer (score 0):

Unix/POSIX only supports 8 bits.  10 bits would be an odd (in both mathematical and logical senses) value, so I'd have to agree with @DigitalRoss.